# Ошибка в методе toString

Tags: java

Пишу свой список, не могу переопределить список. Вот мой метод

```
public String toString(){
   Konj temp = head; return ("[ ");
    while (temp.next != null) {
       return(" "+temp.values);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return(" ]");
}
```

Почему возникает ошибка  unreachable statement?

Comment: С JAVA не сильно знаком, но разве так и должно быть - после Konj temp = head; сразу же return ("[ "); Ведь остальная часть не выполнится.

Или я не прав?

Comment: @BOPOH, ты прав, от языка не зависит.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что в первой же строке вы возвращаете значение "[ " из этого метода и программа возвращается к вызывающему этот код методу.

Вы сначала всё конкатенируйте и только потом делайте return:

```
{
   String result = "";
   Konj temp = head; 
   result += "[ ";
   while (temp.next != null) 
   {
      result += " " + temp.values;
      temp = temp.next;
   }
   result += " ]";
   return result;
}
```

**UPDATED**: как подсказывает [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), можно использовать класс StringBuilder, дабы увеличить производительность этого метода. Делаем это так:

```
{
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
   Konj temp = head; 
   result.append("[");
   while (temp.next != null) 
   {
      result.append(" ").append(temp.values);
      temp = temp.next;
   }
   result.append(" ").append("]");
   return result;
}
```

Comment: ... а ещё лучше использовать [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: А ещё для красоты после открывающей скобки не нужен пробел, он и так будет добавлен в цикле.